# Finding the integral of $x^2\sqrt[3]{1-x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int x^2\sqrt[3]{1-x}dx$$
I'm just starting out integration and found the above question on a textbook. It is meant to be worked out by substitution but even after a day of struggling, I can't get the answer given in the book. I tried substituting u =  $\sqrt[3]{1-x}$ and then tried 1-x = u. On both the cases I am getting an answer but both are different from the answer given in the book. The answer given in the book is :
$$-\frac{3}{140}\left(35-40x+14x^2  \right)\left(  1-x\right)^{4/3}$$
I'm getting a common factor -3 and $(1-x)^{4/3}$ but not 140 and the terms inside the other bracket are different.

Comment: It would be great if you could actually show your steps. We can perhaps find out where you went wrong. Your suggested u-subs are certainly in the right direction...

Comment: @imranfat I'll edit the question now.

Comment: The answer you have given is incorrect. @heropup below has the correct answer.

Comment: @IanMiller Answer is given in the book problems in calculus by I A Maron https://ia600206.us.archive.org/17/items/ProblemsInCalculusOfOneVariableI.A.Maron/Problems%20in%20Calculus%20of%20One%20Variable%20-%20I.%20A.%20Maron.pdf It is question number 4.2.14 (a) and I too believe that the answer is wrong

Comment: @HGSur If you look at the second last line of heropop's answer you can see where the typo in the book came from.

Comment: @IanMiller Indeed, but previously I had a certain faith in the answers given in the book since it was published many years ago(1970s or so) so the author had enough time for correction. Anyway it's a nice book :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the substitution $u = 1-x$, $du = -dx$, we obtain $$\int x^2 (1-x)^{1/3} \, dx = -\int (1-u)^2 u^{1/3} \, du = -\int u^{7/3} - 2u^{4/3} + u^{1/3} \, du.$$  Integrating term by term, we get $$-\frac{3u^{10/3}}{10} + \frac{6u^{7/3}}{7} - \frac{3u^{4/3}}{4} + C.$$  Factoring out a common term of $-\frac{3}{140}u^{4/3}$ we get $$-\frac{3u^{4/3}}{140} (14u^2 - 40u + 35) + C.$$  Expressing this in terms of $x$ gives $$-\frac{3(1-x)^{4/3}}{140} (14x^2 + 12x + 9) + C.$$

---

You should note that in the last step, expressing the antiderivative in terms of $x$ gives a different quadratic factor:  perhaps this is the one you obtained?  The answer that you claim your book has given is not correct.

Comment: @HGSur If you want to be sure an anti derivative is right, make the integral a definite integral (you can use the interval) and figure out the exact area under the curve. Then use an online tool or TI84 to match the decimals...There are plenty of situations where book answers are incorrect.

Comment: One question : How do you know that the common term to be taken out is 3/140 ?

Comment: The greatest common factor of the numerator terms $3$, $6$, $3$ is obviously $3$.  The least common multiple of the denominator terms $10$, $7$, $4$ is $140$.  Therefore, factoring out $3/140$ guarantees that the quadratic factor will have integer coefficients, and that these coefficients will be "minimal" in the sense that they are relatively prime (though not necessarily pairwise relatively prime).

Answer (score 2):

It would be nicer if $x$ carried the exponent $\frac13$ and $(1-x)$ carried the exponent $2$, because you could then just expand the latter and multiply through by the former to produce a simple sum of terms.

So, let's write $u=1-x$ (the thing under the radical). Then we can also get the part outside of the radical in terms of $u$ as well, because then $x=1-u$ and $dx = -du$. So the integral can be written as
$$\int \underbrace{(1-u)^2}_{x^2}\underbrace{u^{1/3}}_{\sqrt[3]{1-x}}\underbrace{(-1)\; du}_{dx}$$
$$=\int -(1-2u + u^2)u^{1/3}\; du$$
$$=-\int (u^{1/3}-2u^{4/3}+u^{7/3})\; du$$
$$=-(\tfrac34u^{4/3} - \tfrac67u^{7/3} + \tfrac3{10}u^{10/3})+C$$
$$=- \left( \tfrac{105}{140}-\tfrac{120}{140}u+\tfrac{42}{140}u^2\right)u^{4/3}+C$$
$$=\tfrac3{140}(35 +40 u + 14 u^2)u^{4/3}+C$$
$$=\tfrac3{140}[35 +40(1-x) + 14 (1-x)^2](1-x)^{4/3}+C$$
$$=\tfrac3{140}[35 -(40-40x) + (14-28x+14x^2)](1-x)^{4/3}+C$$
$$=\boxed{\tfrac3{140}(9 -12 x + 14x^2)(1-x)^{4/3}+C}$$

Answer (score 0):

setting $$t=(1-x)^\frac13$$ then we get $$x=1-t^3$$ and $$dx=-3t^2dt$$ and our integral is $$\int (1-t^3)^2\cdot t\cdot (-3t^2)dt$$ which is simplier.

Comment: I did that too, but as it seems the answer in the book turns out to be wrong.